# fork() return value bug

Tags: c, linux, debugging, fork

In the program below, I mistakenly introduced a bug while calling fork and assigning the return value to childpid (Line 18).

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <unistd.h>
  3 #include <sys/types.h>
  4 #include <stdlib.h>
  5 #include <string.h>
  6
  7 int main(){
  8
  9         int     fd[2], nbytes;
 10         pid_t   childpid = -1;
 11         char    string[] = "Hello, world!";
 12         char    readbuffer[80];
 13
 14         pipe(fd);
 15         printf("Parent: Beginning of Program...\n");
 16
 17
 18         if(childpid = fork() == -1){  // BUG-FIX: Missing parenthesis (childpid=fork())==-1
 19                 printf("childpid == -1\n");
 20                 perror("fork");
 21                 exit(1);
 22         }
 23         if(childpid == 0){
 24                 // child process closes up input of pipe
 25                 close(fd[0]);
 26
 27                 // send string through output side of pipe
 28                 write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
 29                 printf("Child %d: Finished writing to pipe!\n",childpid);
 30                 exit(0);
 31         }
 32         else{
 33                 // parent closes output side of pipe
 34                 close(fd[1]);
 35
 36                 // read in a string from the pipe
 37                 nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
 38                 printf("Parent %d: Received string: %s\n", childpid,readbuffer);
 39         }
 40
 41
 42         printf("Parent %d: End of program\n", childpid);
 43         return 0;
 44 }
```

The buggy output is:

```
$ ./a.exe
Parent: Beginning of Program...
Child 0: Finished writing to pipe!
```

Running it multiple times, I noticed the else block is never reached. Which means somehow the childpid never got assigned a value > 0 inside the parent process. This is strange, since childpid was initialized to -1 to begin with, fork did happen (which is why childpid got a value of 0 in the child process) but the parent process' childpid never got a value > 0 - Why is that?

The fix ofcourse is to surround the assignment with a parenthesis, which gives the output as:

```
$ ./a
Parent: Beginning of Program...
Parent 106648: Received string: Hello, world!
Child 0: Finished writing to pipe!
Parent 106648: End of program
```

I know the fix, but I'm a little unclear how to explain to myself the buggy code's output! Why would childpid get a 0 in the childprocess but not got a positive value in the parent process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  if(childpid = fork() == -1){
```

is equivalent to:

```
  if(childpid = (fork() == -1) ){
```

due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).  `==` (comparison) has higher precedence than `=` (assignment).

So `childpid` will be `0` in *both* processes unless fork() fails (in that case, `childpid` will be `1` in both processes and the `if` block will never be executed). Hence, the `else` block is never executed.

I am not a big fan of using assignments within an `if` statement. I prefer to write it in a separate line so that I don't have to keep operator precedence in my head all the time:

```
childpid = fork();

 if(childpid  == -1){  
   /* error */
}

if ( childpid == 0) {
  ...
}

else {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the buggy version, you wrote

```
    if(childpid = fork() == -1)
```

This first tests if the return value of `fork()` is -1 or not.  Usually, it wouldn't be (the fork succeeded), so it evaluates to false.  A false value is 0.  Then you assign this 0 to `childpid`.  The program continues to line 23:

```
    if(childpid == 0){
```

In which case `childpid` will always be 0, so this block is always executed, never reaching your *else* block below.

An `if` statement tests if something is zero (false) or non-zero (true).  For example:

```
    if ( 0 ) {
```

is valid syntax, and the block will never be executed.  On the other hand,

```
    if ( 1 ) {
```

is also valid, and will always be executed.